# Can multiple clusters run simultaneously using minikube in local machine?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am able to create multiple clusters locally using minikube but unable to find a way to run them simultaneously.

I created 2 clusters using the below command.

```
minikube start --profile <clusterName>
```

Then I switched to particular cluster,

```
kubectl config use-context <clusterName>
```

When I tried to run another cluster by opening a new terminal, it gets switched to the new cluster and the previously running cluster gets stopped.

Is there any possible way to run multiple clusters simultaneously using **minikube**?

Answer (score 2):

I think it has stopped running because it might be using the same port. Have you checked it with `docker ps`?

Comment: Yes, I checked. Both clusters use different ports.